# How can I convert from string to currency when the format is not known?

Tags: python, unicode

I have a bunch of strings coming in:

```
1. $ 148.69
2. € 148.69
3. € 148,69
3. ₹ 148.69
4. Rs 148.69
5. RM 148.69
```

and many more variations. What is the best algorithm to convert these values into currencies? I need to take care of the `"," vs "."` variation as well as the fact that sometimes these strings show up as `"INR\xa0148.69"`. I want to be able to split it into the currency and value tuple. Problem is that the format can vary (basically parsing email receipts from different countries).

Comment: By "the format is not known", do you mean that those dollar signs, etc., will not be present in the actual strings?

Comment: Find patterns in the input, then develop an algorithm to process the patterns, eg.g using _regular expressions_. I suspect, however, some patterns might be ambivalent, so you cannot convert those automatically (perhaps the currency symbol can help, too).

Comment: do you expect [_thousands separators_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Digit_grouping)?

Comment: @RedRoboHood I mean sometimes its Rs 148.69, other times its Rs 148.69 and sometimes its € 148.69 and other times its € 148,69...its basically that currency is represented very differently in different countries and locales. I need something that will be able to parse these intelligently (from email receipts) and return me a (currency, value) tuple.

Comment: What other information do you have that you could use to parse them intelligently?

Comment: These are coming from email receipts. So I know these are currency values from various countries. So I expect them to be consistent within a string. I also know the numbers will not be huge (related to the 'thousands separators' remark), I probably won't get a number like $10,000.79. If that helps.

Comment: Btw, this is coming from a real-world problem I am encountering while parsing invoices from various sources, so I'm guessing someone else should have run into this too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
import re

preg = re.compile(r'^((?P<leading_currency>\S+) +)?'
                  r'(?P<value>[-\d\.,]+)'
                  r'( +(?P<trailing_currency>\S+))?$')
bunch = "$ 148.69\n" \
        "€ 148.69\n" \
        "€ 148,69\n" \
        "148,69 €\n" \
        "₹ 148.69\n" \
        "Rs 148.69\n" \
        "RM 148.69"

def parse_currency(line):
    match = preg.match(line)
    if match:
        currency = match.group('leading_currency') \
                   or match.group('trailing_currency')
        val_str = match.group('value')
        dec_sep = '.' if val_str.rfind('.') > val_str.rfind(',') else ','
        int_part, float_part = val_str.rsplit(dec_sep, 1)
        def norm(number_string):
            return ''.join(c for c in number_string if c.isdigit())
        value = float('{}.{}'.format(norm(int_part), norm(float_part)))
        return currency, value

for line in bunch.splitlines():
    print(parse_currency(line))
```

This way you can

1. Match both currency-before-value and currency-after-value notations
2. parse the value and match the correct decimal separator
3. ignore thousands separator signs

You might want to take a look [here](https://regex101.com/r/iA0sS1/1) to play around with the regular expression for better understanding.

Comment: An updated version of the regex with more awareness about decimal- and thousands-separators can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/iA0sS1/3)